# How can I get Startup Disk Creator to not prompt for password when installing the bootloader on a USB drive?

Tags: startup-disk-creator

I use Startup Disk Creator quite a lot and I find it quite annoying to have to enter my password near the end of the process for the bootloader to be installed. If I don't see the prompt quick enough then I have to start the process all over. How can I get this password prompt to stop?

I know it is a security measure, but what am really risking by turning that one prompt off?

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu 14.04 I ran the utility by command "gksudo usb-creator-gtk" in terminal. Then password is requested at start, but not in the middle of installation anymore.

Comment: I will have to give that a try. That makes sense.